# How to make button in child view to update information in its parent view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So I want to make an iPhone app in which there are two views connected by `UINavigationController`. Let's say that the first view is ViewA and it's the initial view when the app is launched. Then ViewA segues to ViewB which is the other view. There is a `UIButton` A and a `UILabel` A on ViewA and the `UIButton` A segues to ViewB (i.e. when pressing the button, the user is shown ViewB. In ViewB, there is also a `UIButton` B that, when pressed, can update the `UILabel` A in ViewA. (In fact, there should be many `UIButton` Bs in ViewB but let's just say one for simplicity. That's what I want to achieve and here are what I've done.

I've created the two views and a generic `UINavigationController` and rooted ViewA to it so the initial view is correctly shown when the app is launched.

I've set up the `UILabel` A and `UIButton` A in ViewA and connect the `UILabel` A as an outlet property to ViewAViewController.

I've imported `ViewAViewControllerA` in `ViewAViewControllerB`.

I've segued (push mode) `UILabel` A on `View`A to `View` B and it works as intended.

I also know how to update `UILabelA` in   `ViewAViewController` by using `self.UILabelA.text` but I can't do it on `ViewBViewController` because I can't call `self` and I don't know the name of the object of `ViewAViewController`. That is: I think I should use `?.UILabelA.text` but I don't know what should be put to replace `?`.

By the way, I'm using XCode 4.6 and development for iOS 6 with the storyboard mode.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Daughter!!! I always read as son or child. Now you started to identify SEX in Inheritance :)

Comment: Oh yes, it should be child. I don't know what it should be called and I just brought the idea in inheritance to it. I'm going to change it, haha.

Comment: If you have tried to search you could have found dozens of answers for similar questions, and I am sorry I have to vote to close as Dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is to **access object of ClassA from ClassB**.

Here are a lot of ways, and answers here, to do :

[Update a label through button from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257848/update-a-label-through-button-from-different-view)

[Xcode - update ViewController label text from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view)

[Setting label text in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332082/setting-label-text-in-another-class)

[Set label on another view to stored NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081042/set-label-on-another-view-to-stored-nsdate)