# Using object from one class in another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a two `UIViewControllers`, on one of which I want a custom button to be displayed. I have written the code for this. I have also written the code for a popover segue to the other `ViewController`, and as both controllers belong to my 'ViewController' class, the button is also displayed on the second `ViewController`, which I do not want.

Obviously I can create another class and make my second `ViewController` a member of this class, however I want the code for my second `ViewController` to change the colour of the button in the first `ViewController`, so how can I use an object from my first class in the second class `implementation` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a two UIViewControllers, on one of which I want a custom button
>   to be displayed. I have written the code for this. I have also written
>   the code for a popover segue to the other ViewController, and as both
>   controllers are subclasses of my 'ViewController' class, the button is
>   also displayed on the second ViewController, which I do not want.

Why don't you make few property private in first cass so that it doesn't get inherited.

---

> Obviously I can create another class and make my second ViewController
>   a member of this class, however I want the code for my second
>   ViewController to change the colour of the button in the first
>   ViewController, so how can I use an object from my first class in the
>   second class implementation file?

Your main problem is to **access object of ClassA from ClassB**.

Here are a lot of ways, and answers here, to do :

[Update a label through button from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257848/update-a-label-through-button-from-different-view)

[Xcode - update ViewController label text from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view)

[Setting label text in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332082/setting-label-text-in-another-class)

[Set label on another view to stored NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081042/set-label-on-another-view-to-stored-nsdate)