# How to access objects from different classes in Cocoa Programming

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, iboutlet

I have an NSTextField subclass (called "txtField1" and used as Custom Class for a Text Field in my interface builder) and I would like to be able to access an NSComboBox object which present in my interface builder from this class.

This is my code:
txtField1.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface txtField1 : NSTextField

@end
```

txtField.m:

```
#import "txtField1.h"

@implementation txtField1

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    HERE I would like to be able to write something like:
    [combobox SetHidden:YES];
}

@end
```

I would like to be able to set access the combobox SetHidden property, in the mouseDown event.
Can you please tell me how to do that? I have tried different solutions found on internet but didn't obtain anything at all!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using object from one class in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187241/using-object-from-one-class-in-another)

Comment: Every day I see similar question dozen of time, and all has same answer!!!

Comment: have a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248130/make-nscombobox-appear-when-nstextfield-is-clicked

Comment: Solution to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248130/make-nscombobox-appear-when-nstextfield-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Here are a lot of ways, and answers here, to do :

[Update a label through button from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257848/update-a-label-through-button-from-different-view)

[Xcode - update ViewController label text from different view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052594/xcode-update-viewcontroller-label-text-from-different-view)

[Setting label text in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332082/setting-label-text-in-another-class)

[Set label on another view to stored NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081042/set-label-on-another-view-to-stored-nsdate)

EDIT:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    HERE I would like to be able to write something like:
    [combobox SetHidden:YES];
    /*
        use the shared instance of comboBox here and make it hidden.
        Also, you can use binding to make it hidden
    */
}
```

Comment: Sorry but actually none of the answers you suggested helped me. Can you please make me an example?

Comment: `access an NSComboBox object which present in my interface builder from this class.` in which class, it is?

Comment: "use the shared instance of comboBox here and make it hidden."
Can you please make me an example of code since I am a newbie in cocoa programming? thank you.

Comment: Any idea?
I'll try to explain you all what I'm trying to do again: I have an NSTextfield and an NSComboBox. Well I want the NSTextField to disappear and the NSComboCox to appear when some one clicks inside the NSTextField. Help me. Thank you.

Comment: have a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248130/make-nscombobox-appear-when-nstextfield-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view `txtField1` class is not better place to this code.

You can add `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` protocol to your `NSViewController` implementation (that already contains `IBOutlet`s for `txtField1` and `combobox`) and in method `– control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` implement hiding of your `NSComboBox`

Comment: Any idea?
I'll try to explain you all what I'm trying to do again: I have an NSTextfield and an NSComboBox. Well I want the NSTextField to disappear and the NSComboCox to appear when some one clicks inside the NSTextField. Help me. Thank you.

Comment: have a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248130/make-nscombobox-appear-when-nstextfield-is-clicked